# Using DiscretePlot to graph the Riemann sum of a parabola

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to graph the Riemann sum (upper sum) of $y=x^2$ with $1\leq x\leq 4$ using 6 rectangles. I want the rectangles to be green.

On the [Wolfram Mathworld website](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html), I can render exactly what I want and I get the following:
[image]

Now, I am trying to render exactly the same thing in *Mathematica* itself, but I have absolutely no idea what to do.

I already tried using the following code:

```
Show[DiscretePlot[x^2, {x, 1, 4, 0.5}, ExtentSize -> Left], Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4}]]
```

which renders the following:

[image]

How should I modify my code to get the picture that the Wolfram Alpha website renders? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before asking a question search for similar questions (to avoid possible duplicates, it is one by the way), then register your account. After all, you are welcome!

Comment: If you check the examples on the documentation page of `DiscretePlot`, you'll find lots and lots which change the styling.  Have you looked at these?

Comment: Yes I did, and I was able to change the color to green, but I was not able to find out how the bordering works and how to set the domain to $1\leq x\leq 4$. Could you please help a bit?

Comment: Do you get what you need if you use `BaseStyle-> EdgeForm[Black]` in `Show`? Alternatively,  `BaseStyle-> EdgeForm[Black]`  or `PlotStyle-> EdgeForm[Black]` in `DiscretePlot`?

Comment: Sure, but you need to be very specific with your questions.  In your original question you seem to be asking about how to make it green, but it turns out you already know how to do this.  Then in a comment you ask a completely different question about changing the domain and the borders.  Can you edit your question, show what you have so far, and explain *precisely* what is missing?

Comment: Please do change the link, you're not on Wolfram Alpha but on WolframMathWorld. [WolframMathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html).

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way using a different set of `DiscretePlot`'s options.

```
Show[
  DiscretePlot[x^2, {x, 1, 4, 0.5},
    PlotRange -> {{1, 4.01}, {0, 16.01}},
    PlotRangeClipping -> True,
    AxesLabel -> {x, x^2},
    Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[0, 16, 2]},
    ExtentSize -> Left,
    ColorFunction -> (Green &),
    ExtentElementFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle @@ Transpose @ #} &)],
  Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks so much! This was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

This is nontrivial due to [`PlotRangeClipping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping.html), [`FaceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceForm.html), [`FaceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceForm.html), etc.

```
Show[
 DiscretePlot[x^2, {x, 1, 4, 0.5}, ExtentSize -> Left,
  PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, {0, 16}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, FaceForm[{Opacity[1], Green}], EdgeForm[Black]], 
  Ticks -> {Automatic, Range[2, 16, 2]}],
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Black]],
 PlotRangeClipping -> True,
 BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Black],
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "\!\(x\^2\)"}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To render the filling rectangles with black edges, you can use the option `FillingStyle` with `EdgeForm[Black]`:

```
Show[DiscretePlot[x^2, {x, 1, 4, 0.5}, ExtentSize -> Left,
  FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Green, EdgeForm[Black]]],
 Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]]]
```

[image]

You can also use `Epilog` in `DiscretePlot` to have all graphics primitives in a single plot:

```
DiscretePlot[x^2, {x, 1, 4, 0.5}, ExtentSize -> Left, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Green, EdgeForm[Black]],
 Epilog ->  Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]][[1]]] 
(* same picture *)
```

**Update:** in version 9,

```
dp = DiscretePlot[x^2, {x, 1, 4, 0.5}, ExtentSize -> Left,
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[{Green, Opacity[1]}]}]]
```

renders the rectangles with `` Opacity[.2`] ``

[image]

```
dp[[1]]
```

[image]

Adding the option `FillingStyle->Opacity[1]` gives the correct opacity for the rectangles:

```
DiscretePlot[x^2, {x, 1, 4, 0.5}, ExtentSize -> Left, 
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[1],
 PlotStyle -> Directive[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[{Green, Opacity[1]}]}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can post-process to remove the `` Opacity[.2`] `` directive:

```
dp /. Opacity[.2`] -> Sequence[]
(* same picture *)
```

Comment: and and +1 over here because `FillingStyle` is better than `FaceForm`.

Comment: I have no idea why this answer has fewer votes than the other two.